# Read PHP array from mysql query as string in c#

Tags: c#, php, mysql, arrays, windows-10

I have a PHP file and a C# app.
In the php file it returns a Array of the rows that i selected from a mysql table.
I want to read that Array and deserialize it so the result of a row can be parsed inside a textBlock.
My PHP script:

```
    <?php
mysql_connect("-----", "------", "-----") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("------");

$list = array();
$query = "SELECT SongName,ArtistName,Thumbnail,MediaLink FROM Library";
$resource = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource))
{
   $list['SongName' . (1 + count($list))] = $row['SongName'];
}
$list = array('row' => count($list)) + $list;
echo json_encode(array($list));
?>
```

How do i get the ArtistName, Thumbnail and medialink inside the array?
How do i read this in C# so my textblock will show: ArtistName.
Technologies:
Windows 10 Store apps(C#, XAML)

If somebody could help that'd be great,

Christos K

Comment: Why not use Json.NET ( https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json )?

Comment: @stdob-- i know but i don't know the methods to deserialize it!

Comment: @stdob-- OMG THANK YOU! i used:    HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync("somesite/testt.php");
                string array = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                string json = array;
           var xd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Customer>>(json);
                foreach (var item in xd)
                {
                    listView.Items.Add(item.SongName);
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple, you pull all the required data from the database and return it as an array, just put the whole $row into the array you are about to return

```
<?php
mysql_connect("-----", "------", "-----") or
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("------");

$list = array();

$query = "SELECT SongName,ArtistName,Thumbnail,MediaLink FROM Library";
$resource = mysql_query($query);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource))
{
   $list[] = $row;
}

echo json_encode($list);
?>
```

Now you should receive all the data you want in the javascript. Just use the javascript debugger to see what it looks like